# Disable open-relay in exchange 2003 behind NAT

Tags: exchange, spam

I have an exchange 2003 which is authoritative for my only one domain. It's in my DMZ and NAT'ed.

I am an open relay, sending thousands of spams. I want to stop it but I still want to receive email *from* any domain, but just *to* my domain.

So I have to let anonymous auth checked and can't use the relay "allow only from" whitelist IP since the source IP is the same if requests comes from outside or inside (due to the NAT'ed architecture)

What are my options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand how it works...normal mail servers without an open relay DO accept/receive email from ANY domain for their local domain.  Think of a post office...it doesn't care where the mail comes from...only that it is destined for a recipient at that PO.

You can follow this link to close the open relay:  http://nurinet.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/disable-open-smtp-server-relay-on-windows-exchange-server-2003/

You should only allow relaying for specific reasons, such as allowing an internal server that needs to send SMTP email but cannot authenticate to Exchange...other than that you should lock it down.  You should NEVER be running an Open Relay.

You'll still get email for your domain.  NAT is irrelevant, almost everyone's Exchange server is behind a NAT firewall.  If closing the Open Relay is causing you issues receiving and sending email on your actual domain then something else is configured incorrectly.

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I use an external SMTP relay (configured as SmartHost - because on the internet connection the server is one, 25 is blocked by ISP), so in the SMTP connector, "Allow messages to be relayed to these domains" is checked. It's overriding the default SMTP settings right ?

Comment: You don't need the "allow messages to be relayed" checked to send to a Smarthost.  You need to uncheck that box.  The smarthost end should also be setup to only accept email from your "domain.com" from your particular external IP address that Exchange is sending from...to prevent others from sending that smarthost mail as you.